# RealityKit – How disable the model's gravity programmatically?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I want to programmatically disable gravity in RealityKit without any help of Reality Composer.

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable model's gravity using `components[PhysicsBodyComponent]`:

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
let entity = boxAnchor.steelBox! as! (Entity & HasPhysics)
    
entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent] = .none

arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
```

Or using `physicsBody` instance property:

```
entity.physicsBody = .none
```